# how to display in front-end from self.class.get(path)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have defined `list_ofresult#

```
def list_ofresult(result_id)
    with_login do
      expect_success do
        self.class.get("/result/#{result_id}")
      end
    end
  end
```

and then in a method I have:

```
 def load_value
    PdsBackend.list_ofresult(self.result_id)
  end

  def value_for
    self.load_value['value']
  end
```

and then I want to display this value attribute in the front-end

```
 %p=@analysis.value
```

but I get error `undefined method 'value' for #<Analysis:0xfcb01d...>
Did you mean?  value_for`

Seems like I am not getting something right here, don't know how to display this value I have in the backend.

Any hint would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Re-read the error message, it basically contains _all_ the information you need to fix an issue.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin but value is not meant to be a method. I'ts a variable I want to display in the frontend from the backend, therefore I am confused

Comment: Then please share code that declares that variable. What you have shown declares the method `value_for` that supposedly is what you need in the view.